# Using the mono profiler with app bundle on osx

Tags: c#, macos, mono, memory-profiling, xamarin.mac

I'm trying to profile an application bundle generated through by using the command line mono parameter *--profile* but i can't get it to work.

Calling the on the exe located in the .app bundle will result in this :

> No Info.plist file in application bundle or no NSPrincipalClass in the Info.plist file, exiting

Otherwise, inside Xamarin Studio, in *Project Options -> Run -> General* you can set environment variables but they seems to be totally ignored when you run the application through the xam.mac debugger.

My only success so far has been to use a bash script and doing stuff like *export MONO_LOG_LEVEL="debug"*, enabling mono's logs you can't get through the UI. But again i can't get it to add the *--profile* parameter needed.

Notes:

1. I'm using the mono runtime (3.2.6) and xamarin studio (4.2.3)
2. I can't changed my app to a console app
3. This is *not* a monotouch application but a full fledge osx app

Comment: Does your project has an info.plist file and NSPrincipalClass is defined in it?

Comment: yup it work correctly when launching from finder or with *open* command from a terminal. It's really question about sending extra parameters to the mono runtime for profiling purpose.

Comment: But did you checked there is a info.plist and it has defined NSPrincipalClass?

Comment: to answer your question, yes it has a plist file, as i said the app can run. I think this might be because of the where the mono executable is located and the plist got to be somewhere related to that. In all case this seems to be a distraction from my main question.